# make old boot drive a data drive - make it unbootable

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have a 1TB drive that looks like this:

```
$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000409264 sectors, 953.9 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): D02C689D-715F-4380-B810-D0624582A381
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 2000409230
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2669 sectors (1.3 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1640447   800.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   2         1640448        12126207   5.0 GiB     0C01  Basic data partition
   3        12126208      2000408575   948.1 GiB   8300

Command (? for help):
```

I cloned the disk successfully using the dd command, booted off of the clone as sda,
and mounted the old disk using a usb cable as sdb.

My issue is if I put this disk back in the machine internally it boots from it and not the new disk.

How can I make this sdb non-bootable?

I don't want it to mount or anything, After the new disk boots up,  this disk should show up as an unmounted /dev/sdx[1-3]

thanks, jleslie

Comment: lIf you cloned it, you cannot have duplicate UUID nor GUIDs.

Comment: @oldfred, I'm sure I do as I cloned the disk, so how do I fix this?   I boot the new disk, I then put the old disk onto a usb cable so it comes in as sdb, with its 3 partitions, sdb1, sdb2, and sdb3.   At this point I want to ensure that this disk is no longer capable of booting, I will gladly change its UUID, or GUID, but I need to be able to do that from the command line.   I assume I only have to do this once, and now the drives 3rd partiton (the 948GB partition,) will be a backup disk.

Comment: If the answer is satisfactory, you can mark it as answered. Please visit the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You need to unmount the disk first, then restart `gdisk`...

**At the gdisk prompt:**
Type a `?` and `enter` to display the available options.
Then - from what is displayed, find the options to delete partitions,
and all partition table(s)
until the there is "nothing" left.

At that point: create one clean partition table, and at least one partition. That partition will be "unbootable" as long as you do NOT actively make it bootable.

Exit gdisk.

Do `$ lsblk -p` and find what the new partition ended up as *(probably /dev/sdb1)* and do
`$ udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sdb1`
to make it available in `/media/$USER/` where `$USER` is your user name.

To have it available at every boot, without the need for the above `mount` you need to find the correct settings to fill in on a single line in `/etc/fstab`
*(`sudo nano /etc/fstab` - to edit the file, in a nice easy editor, assuming you have nano installed)*

At  this point; what `$ mount | grep sdb` displays might be a start for that line, it might need some amending though.

---

**To keep partitions and mark the disk "not bootable".**

Either boot a "live disk" (e.g. Ubuntu install media in "try mode") with gparted present or do `sudo apt install gparted` from a shell/terminal.

Run gparted, Click on the first partition on your disk, goto Partition > Manage flags... in the menu.
That option not being present or greyed out: Try other partitions(!?) - generally the disk shouldn't be bootable if so.

Comment: thank you hannu!  you are very close!   the thing is, I don't want to delete partition #3, I want that one left alone it is the / root directory with the users files in /home/xyz1, /home/xyz2, etc.   Can I get buy with leaving that partition in tact and still have a non-bootable drive?

Comment: bonus question, Is there a way to leave all the partitions, but just "turn off" the bootable flag easily so I could turn it back on should I decide I would like to be able to boot this drive at a later date?

Comment: not deleting partitions and partition table: You need to investigate `gdisk` options to find how to disable the boot option from that disk. if gdisk doesn't have the correct options; you need to find another partition editor that supports / has these "right" GPT-options (gparted possibly?) -   sorry can't help there.

Comment: thanks again hannu.  so the bonus question is still a TBD, but what about leaving the one / root partition (the 948.1 gb partition,) and only deleting the other ones?   will that keep this disk from booting but still allow me to mount the 948gb partition after the machine is booted on the other disk?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with GPT. MBR has a "bootable" flag. But you have GPT. `gparted` (sudo apt install gparted) has a bootable flag: Click on the first partition on your disk, goto Partition > Manage flags... in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reboot with a cloned drive connected. UEFI or BIOS may boot one drive or the other, or even part of one and part of the other, getting them out of sync.

You can use sgdisk to change GUIDs. This changes them all where sdX is your drive that you want to change.
Best to have good backups.

```
man sgdisk
sudo sgdisk -G /dev/sdX
```

> -G, --randomize-guids
> Randomize the disk's GUID and all partitions' unique GUIDs (but not their partition type code GUIDs). This  func‐
> tion may be used after cloning a disk in order to render all GUIDs once again unique.

You can change UUIDs with uuidgen or tune2fs.

```
man tune2fs
man uuidgen

sudo tune2fs -U random /dev/sdaX
```

This shows both UUID & partUUID/GUID

```
lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid | egrep -v "^loop"
```

After these changes the cloned drive could be made bootable again only if grub reinstalled & all UUIDs in fstab manually updated. There may be other UUID references that also need to be changed like /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume if swap partition.

Comment: this is wrong.   I can definitely "reboot with a cloned drive connected. UEFI or BIOS may boot one drive or the other"   I've done it it works.   The only issue is I don't know which drive it is booting.  That is why I want to disable one of the two drives.  So lets say I've booted on drive 1 as sda,  I then use a usb cable to hook up drive 2 through the usb port, and the system recognizes drive 2 as sdb.

Comment: sdb has 3 partitions;  <br/>
    
     1            2048         1640447   800.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
     2         1640448        12126207   5.0 GiB     0C01  Basic data partition
     3        12126208      2000408575   948.1 GiB   8300
    
    I want the data in parition 3 left in tact, but I want this drive to never boot.   
    
    I need to make this drive 2 such that  when it it internal, the bios or whatever won't boot it but instead boots drive 1 all the time.

Comment: sgdisk worked.   thank you

Comment: tun2fs only worked on the ext4 partition. as that is the only one I want, can I just delete the other two partitions, and then this drive 2 will be a data disk that is not bootable?

Comment: Well, ok you can reboot, but system may not even always boot into the same drive. And once out of sync the clone becomes worthless. If you remove ESP if UEFI then it will not be bootable. But if MBR, it will still have grub in MBR. Normally we do not erase MBR, just install new boot loader. Often suggesting dd to new users can be dangerous as they erase the wrong thing.  I like to have an install of Ubuntu on every drive, just for emergency boot.

Comment: thanks again for your advise oldfred.   This installation has security issues and as it is, grub is not an option.  I simply want to render this disk so it can't boot.  when this drive and the cloned drive are both internal to the Computer, I don't want this drive to boot EVER.  IF I delete partition 1 and partition 2, will the computer bood off of the other drive and when the other drive is booted up, I can mount the partition 3 of the drive that I deleted partition 1 and 2 off of?

Comment: If BIOS, you have to tell system to boot correct drive. If UEFI deleting partition will prevent it from booting that drive as it will only see the other cloned drive. Some users have UEFI, but also managed to install a BIOS boot loader version of grub to MBR which then does not work leading to grub> . After you delete partitions, run the Boot-Repair summary report. Be sure to boot in correct mode UEFI or BIOS and do not run any suggested fix. Use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair